# If I want to explain, the redshift through decay of photon, how much mass should photon have?

Tags: general-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, space-expansion

Any thing that has mass decays with some decay width, similarly if I want to explain redshift by considering massive photon, how much should be the mass?
Is it less than today's upper limit.

EDIT

Solution of wave equation
$\square \phi =0 $ gives a wave that doesn't disperse over time.

But wave solution of the form $(\square + m^2)\phi =0$ has some dispersion
If I consider a wave traveling with speed v from A point to B point there will be some dispersion,

Now consider a wave-packet from point A and it is observed that at point B its wavelength has increased due to dispersion,

Now how to calculate the $m$ for a wave, and

***why can't one apply this to electromagnetic waves***

Comment: What would the photon decay into in your model? Via what mechanism?

Comment: Hydrogen atom in ground state has mass; the constituent proton and electron also has mass, are they supposed to decay? 

decay width is usually represented as an imaginary part to the eigenenergy of the Hamiltonian operator. If it is purely real valued, there should be no decaying.

Comment: Look at the recent experimental limit https://www.science.org/content/article/incredible-shrinking-photon-mass and theconversion table here to see it cannot be so  https://quarknet.fnal.gov/toolkits/ati/whatgevs.html

Answer (score 3):

Cosmological redshift is not due to decay of a photon instead it is due to its increasing wavelength in an expanding universe.
Moreover a photon is a massless "particle", so it can't decay,